# Average value for top n records?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this SQL Schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb34d

In particular these are the relevant columns for this question:

```
ut_id,ob_punti
```

**I need to get the average of the TOP n (where n is 4) values of "ob_punti" for each user (ut_id)**

This query returns the AVG of all values of ob_punti grouped by ut_id:

```
SELECT ut_id, SUM(ob_punti), AVG(ob_punti) as coefficiente 
       FROM vw_obiettivi_2015 
       GROUP BY ut_id ORDER BY ob_punti DESC
```

But i can't figure out how to get the AVG for only the TOP 4 values.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will give SUM and AVG of top 4. You may replace 4 by n to get top `n`.

```
select ut_id,SUM(ob_punti), AVG(ob_punti) from (
select @rank:=if(@prev_cat=ut_id,@rank+1,1) as rank,ut_id,ob_punti,@prev_cat:=ut_id

from Table1,(select @rank:=0, @prev_cat:="")t
order by ut_id, ob_punti desc
  ) temp
  where temp.rank<=4
group by ut_id;
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer! I get a single line result (in the production enviroment) while i need the AVG and SUM for EACH ut_id (about 100). Thanks again

Comment: @eldblz : If the answer resolves your query then you should accept it as answer.

Comment: sorry but does not resolve the request i need the AVG for top 4 ob_punti for EACH ut_id your query returns only one row!

Comment: @eldblz : There is no filter applied in this query. and it will calculate rank for each `ut_id` separately. Kindly create some data at sqlfiddle to check. Please keep relevant field, remove unnecessary fields.

Comment: @eldblz: Please check and let me know. Its working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3513/3  `group by` clause was missing in the query. I regret for the inconvenience.

Comment: with group by works perfectly! Thanks. If i want to apply some filter (for example filter by year) i have to do so in the sub-query (the one inside brackets) right?

Comment: @eldblz : Yes, you are right. Any data that shouldn't be used for rank calculation, filter it in sub-query.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. Something like this right? http://pastie.org/10401382 @seahawk

Comment: @eldblz : there are two cases: 1. filter data before rank calculation. 2. Filter data after rank calculation. In my opinion, you want to filter data before rank calculation. If it is so, keep the `where clause` before `order by` in inner query/subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly related to the question asked, I am placing this because some one might get benefited.

I got the hackerearth problem to write mysql query to fetch top 10 records based on average of product quantity in stock available.

```
SELECT productName, avg(quantityInStock) from products 
group by quantityInStock 
order by quantityInStock desc
limit 10
```

Note: If someone can make better the above query, please welcome to modify.